# how to pass a link from JSON file to url in android?

Tags: java, android, url

I want to reload image from url, I am parsing JSON file so I am reading the URL link as string.

```
String url = attributeobject.getString(DMG_Image);
URL image = new URL(url);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

but I get `MalformedURLException`  ?

Comment: try to log `url` value , see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String url = attributeobject.getString(DMG_Image);    
URL image = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) image.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: How the link looks like? I mean is looks like "http://www. abc.com" or "abc.com"? Print it out after "getString" method.

Comment: "http://devmaps.mopw.gov.ae/static/img/projects/al_qassimi_hospital.jpg" this is the link

Comment: thank u ,but it did not work  when i run it , i used picassu library and it worked ..